# Cannot select List as a data source in C# visual studio designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a WinForm with a Listbox, and a class which contains a List I want to use for a data source.

DataSource property for the Listbox wont give me the option for the List I want to use. I know I cannot add this list to the DataSource through designer.cs as its generated and the line just disappears, but..

If I add this to designer.cs it works, until the code disappears:

```
`this.listbox1.DataSource = Namespace1.MyWinform.MyList.ToArray();`
```

Only looks like I have no choice but to use the designer properties. How may I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Write this code in form_load?

Comment: @chetan that's the ticket, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chetan's comment suggests,the solution is to add the code into the "form_load":

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listbox1.DataSource = Namespace1.MyWinform.MyList.ToArray();
        }
```